# CodeIgniter não encontra o Controller

Tags: php, iis, codeigniter-3

Meu site está publicado no IIS

```
servidor\c\inetpub\wwwroot\site
```

Existem outros sites na pasta wwwroot cada um em seu diretório (site2, site3, site4... etc)

No routes.php o controller default está apontando para o home.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

A questão é: 
Ao chamar o site ele abre normalmente a home (servidor/site/home), porém, quando tento acessar qualquer outro controller (via link ou diretamente na url) ele retorna erro 404. ex: servidor/site/administracao (em localhost esse erro não ocorre).

A impressão que tenho é que o CI está entendendo que o controller administracao (por exemplo) não está dentro do diretório controller da estrutura do CI, ou que existe mais diretório até o controller ex: controller/site/administracao.php

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: controller/site/Administracao.php - A versão do CI 3 tem esse detalhe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o CI 3, você precisa definir (em alguns servidores), seu controller tanto o nome do arquivo, quanto o nome do controller com letra maiúscula.

```
Class Administrador extends CI {
    function index(){
        return "Teste";
    }
}
```

Seu arquivo se chama Administrador.php, com a primeira letra maiúscula. O mesmo vale para o model. `Model_administrador e Model_administrador.php`

Comment: Boa, valeu, deu certo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo config.php dentro da pasta config tem $config['base_url']. Você precisa referenciar certinho ai a pasta /site